# Java Interfaces?

Tags: java, oop

I really need help with interfaces in general...

Any resources that you guys would recommend me?

#### Related:

- [How are Java interfaces actually used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504904/how-are-java-interfaces-actually-used)
- [Java interface and inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215437/java-interface-and-inheritance)
- [Java Interface Usage Guidelines — Are getters and setters in an interface bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130294/java-interface-usage-guidelines-are-getters-and-setters-in-an-interface-bad)
- [Why can’t I define a static method in a Java interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512877/why-cant-i-define-a-static-method-in-a-java-interface)

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8531292/1055241   check out the accepted answer to understand the concept of interfaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[What is an Interface?](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) from Java's official tutorial

Edit: A second resource from the same tutorial, is the [Interfaces and Inheritence](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) section.

Answer (score 5):

In general:

You can see an interface as a contract or an agreement between two parties. So they can develop independently as long as the interface does not change.

The calling party, knows which behaviour is available and the implementing party knows what to implement.

There are a lot of advantages by using interfaces. One of them is that it is easy to switch between implementations. The other one is that classes can have different (inter)faces without using multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at this excellent book by Bruce Eckel (free available in electronic format) :
[Thinking in Java](http://mindview.net/Books/TIJ/DownloadSites)

Comment: Its very lengthy for a java tutorial

Comment: But i upvoted to welcome you to the community :)

Comment: Thanks ! That's not indeed a tutorial but the book is really worth reading :)

Answer (score 0):

Interface is just like Java class but it contain only abstract method and final attribute.Basically interface are used to achieve "Polymorphic" behavior.

[Here is the detail coding example](http://theprogrammingsintroduction.blogspot.com/2014/07/what-is-interface-in-java.html)