# Is there a difference between Map and Hashmap?

Tags: java, dictionary

I've seen people use Map instead of HashMap to declare a HashMap.

e.g. **Map mapName = new HashMap();**
Whereas I'd normally use **HashMap mapName = new HashMap();**;

The same for a a HashSet, I've seen **Set setName = new HashSet()**;  used,
whereas I'd normally use a **HashSet setName = new HashSet()**

Same for ArrayList (List) and so on.

My question is, is there any benefit to doing this, or is it just a matter a perspective?

Comment: Every hashmap is a map, but not every map is a hashmap.

Answer (score 6):

`Map` is the name of the interface, which garantees a number of implemented methods.

`HashMap` is the name of a class that implements the aforementionned interface.

However, `HashMap` is not the only class to implement the `Map` interface. Other classes that do can be found on the Java doc Map page.

Useful links:

[Java Interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416331/java-interfaces)

[What is the difference between the HashMap and Map objects in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348199/java-hashmap-vs-map-objects)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: Adding a little more information to your answer. It is important to mention that's a bad practice doing HashMap map = new HashMap();. The good practice is always having the interface at left side in the way of: Map map = new HashMap(). Many quality source tools like FindBug point this as important change.

Answer (score 3):

As @AntonH mentioned, `Map` is the interface and `HashMap` is a concrete implementation of that interface.

To answer the final part of your question, the benefit to doing this is that it makes your code more flexible for no cost.  It means that any implementation of the interface can be "plugged in" at the point where it's constructed, and the rest of the code doesn't have to change.

This applies not only to alternative implementations in the core library (`HashMap` vs `TreeMap`, for example); but to other custom implementations too (someone might write a `ListeningMap` which has hooks to be notified when an entry is added, for example).

If you wrote a method to accept a `HashMap` argument, then people could only ever pass it HashMaps.  It would force callers to adopt a particular data storage, or have the overhead of casting every time they called it.  And it would prevent them from doing any interesting logic (such as the aforementioned listeners, or a `Map` that calculates its entries dynamically).

So unless you really, *specifically* need for the value to be a HashMap (which is almost never the case), declaring your types as the broadest possible interface gives a lot of flexibility.

Comment: +1 for mentioning custom `Map`s.

Answer (score 0):

[`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is an interface, i.e. an abstract "thing" that defines how something can be used.

[`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is an implementation of that interface.

[image]