# Cardslib's CardView OnCardClickListener's onClick method not being called

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, cardslib

I am using this library in my app: [Card Library : Guide](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/GUIDE.md#feature) and created a card as shown in the example.
Now I need to handle a click event, but I receive an error when instantiating the following: `new Card.OnCardClickListener`, which says `OnCardClickListener is abstract: cannot be instantiated`.
In my Activity I have this code:

```
    Card card = new Card(getBaseContext());//getContext()
    CardHeader header = new CardHeader(getBaseContext());
    card.addCardHeader(header);
    final CardViewNative cardView = (CardViewNative) findViewById(R.id.carddemo);
    cardView.setCard(card);

    cardView.setClickable(true);
    cardView.setOnClickListener(new Card.OnCardClickListener()); //error here
```

What's wrong? How can I set my card as clickable and then handle click/touch events?

**EDIT**

If I use it this way:

```
cardView.setOnClickListener(new Card.OnCardClickListener(){//error here
        @Override
        public void onClick(Card card, View view) {
            // This will execute when the the card is clicked
        }
    });
```

it says `cannot resolve method setOnClickListener(it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.internal.Card.OnCardClickListener)`

**EDIT1**

You guys are right, I set the `setOnClickListener` on the card itself, and there's no error anymore, 
**but still it doesn't perform any action** when the card is clicked. That's the new code:

```
     //Create a Card
    Card card = new Card(this);//getContext()

    //Create a CardHeader
    CardHeader header = new CardHeader(this);
    //....
    //Add Header to card
    card.addCardHeader(header);

    //Set card in the cardView
    CardViewNative cardView = (CardViewNative) this.findViewById(R.id.carddemo);
    cardView.setCard(card);

    card.setClickable(true);
    card.setOnClickListener(new Card.OnCardClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(Card card, View view) {
            // This will execute when the the card is clicked
            Toast.makeText(CardMariotti.this,"Clickable card", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

I performed a debug, but the `onClick` method is never called. How come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Card.OnCardClickListener is an Interface. You must create the class that defines how the functions within the interface are to be used. Try this:

```
card.setOnClickListener(new Card.OnCardClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(Card card, View view) {
        // This will execute when the the card is clicked
    }
});
```

Source for answer: https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/CARD.md#clickable-card

Information on Java interfaces: [Java Interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416331/java-interfaces)

**EDIT**

Furthermore, remove `android:clickable="true"` from the RelativeLayout contained by the card. It's stealing the click for itself.

Comment: I tried it like you said and I have another error. See my edit

Comment: Sorry, change cardView.setOnClickListener to card.setOnClickListener

Answer (score 2):

I've found the error but I don't know how to handle it. 
It's in the layout containing the card, `cardslib_item_card.xml`. If I remove everything that I've added and I just keep this:

```
<it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardViewNative     xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    card:card_layout_resourceID="@layout/native_card_layout"
    style="@style/native_recyclerview_card.base"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/carddemo"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp" android:layout_marginRight="12dp">
```

then the card gets clicked, but if try to personalize it, for example adding a Relative Layout, as such:

```
<it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardViewNative     
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    card:card_layout_resourceID="@layout/native_card_layout"
    style="@style/native_recyclerview_card.base"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/carddemo"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp" android:layout_marginRight="12dp">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/cardlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"              
        android:clickable="true">
    <!-- layout containing 3 TextViews -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardViewNative>
```

then the card doesn't get clicked anymore. 
To be more precise, it gets clicked just sometimes, as if the RelativeLayout is covering the whole card and and when i find a spot where it's not then it detects my finger. It works if I only add an empty card, but how am I supposed to customize it then?

It's like having two views on top of each other

Comment: Remove android:clickable="true" from the RelativeLayout. It's stealing the click for itself.

Comment: Your last comment worked! you should consider editing your last answer so I will accept it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the clickListener on the `card` (model) instead of `CardView` (view)

```
//Set onClick listener
card.setOnClickListener(new Card.OnCardClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Card card, View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Clickable card", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

At the same time you should use:

```
   //it is not necessary if you define a ClickListener on the card
   card.setClickable(true);
```

Btw, you should also use something like this in an `Activity`:

```
Card card = new Card(this);
```

Comment: Ok there's no error now but still the method doesn't perform any action. See my EDIT1. –

Comment: ok, I've run the debug but no, the `onClick` seems to be never called.... -Basically, when I press the card nothing seems to happen... why? do I need to post other details?

Comment: I've also changed the `getBaseContext()` method and used `Card card = new Card(this);` instead, as shown in EDIT1. But still doesn't make the `onClick` method to be called.

Comment: To solve it I've tried a workaround, creating a `RelativeLayout` object referencing to the RelativeLayout view inside the `cardview` in the xml file, and setting the `onCardClickListener` on the RelativeLayout object:  it's working this way, but I don't think that this was how the `cardslib`` is supposed to be used!

Comment: @CrisBenois of course you can use library without this workaround. I don't know what it is your issue

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti can you please view this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297099/cardlib-topcoloredcard-setupinnerelements-is-not-called