# Set onClickListener on the RelativeLayout contained by CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am trying to set the `onClickListener` on each of my `CardView` elements. 
Since I was not able to set the `onClickListener` on the cards themselves (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926073/cardslibs-cardview-oncardclicklistener-is-abstract-cannot-be-instantiated/29926842#29926842)), I thought about setting it to the RelativeLayout contained by the cards. Right now I am using the native CardView library and applied [this](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156) tutorial.

Here's my `MainActivity`'s `onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recycleCardView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
    recycleCardView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager llmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llmanager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recycleCardView.setLayoutManager(llmanager);

    data = createList(9);

    ContactAdapter ctadapter = new ContactAdapter(data);
    //...
    recycleCardView.setAdapter(ctadapter);
```

this is the `item_card_view` xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
       xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/card_view"
       android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
       card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
       android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/nativecardlayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground">        

      <!--some more layout-->

    </RelativeLayout>
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

here's my `ContactAdapter`'s `onCreateViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.item_card_view, viewGroup, false);

    RelativeLayout cardlayout = (RelativeLayout)
              viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.nativecardlayout); //NullPointerException here
    cardlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(viewGroup.getContext(), "Clickable card", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return new ContactViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

My problem is that the RelativeLayout that I am trying to load, which is inside the `cardview` element, is null. Therefore I get a `NullPointerException`.

How can I set `onClickListener` on each RelativeLayout? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below edit, its logical mistake:

```
RelativeLayout cardlayout = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.nativecardlayout);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! what if I want to set the `onClickListener` depending on the position `int i`?

Comment: no I got it, nevermind. (your former edit was correct). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set a listener to all Views. So it's possibile.

replace this

```
RelativeLayout cardlayout = (RelativeLayout)
          viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.nativecardlayout);
```

with this

```
RelativeLayout cardlayout = (RelativeLayout)
          itemView.findViewById(R.id.nativecardlayout);
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's gonna produce a NPE. You make a new reference called cardlayout(`RelativeLayout cardlayout[...]`), and then you try to use a method of the cardLayout(`cardlayout.findViewById(...)`)...which hasn't been initialized yet.