# What's the point of Interfaces?

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

I'm having trouble understanding why I should use interfaces, and how I should integrate them into my current project. I use a lot of polymorphism already, and I usually see polymorphism and interfaces side by side in other projects of my peers.

Why do you use interfaces? What are the real benefits?

Comment: Start here http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/131332

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered in:

[When should one use interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686174/when-should-one-use-interfaces)

[What is an interface in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321122/what-is-an-interface-in-java)

[Java Interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416331/java-interfaces)

To get more information about OOP design you can also refer to books like [Head First: Object oriented analysis and design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008678). There are also some on-line courses on platforms like [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [Edx](http://edx.org) that you can use.

Comment: Please don't post duplication links as a new answer. Post them as a comment or vote to close the question as duplicate.